# c# storing thread reference for later termination

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to start up a thread, storing it as a reference and then terminate it on a button click. But after starting the thread and having it execute some work, the reference has false in "IsAlive" and looking at the Thread.CurrentThread doesn't give me the same as i stored on execution.

Why can't i start a thread and later abort it from the same reference as i started it from?

Thread thread = new Thread(start);
thread.Start();

```
Thread thread = new Thread(start);
thread.Start();

void start (){`
await something();
No longer same thread
```

Could somebody explain why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it sounds like it already completed...? what is the method you're using here? (`start`)

Comment: Please show the code that starts, stops, and keeps the thread reference. Also, as a side-note, "aborting" threads is not a nice thing to do, it's much better to use cooperative termination in which you use any of the many mechanisms built into .NET to ask the thread to terminate nicely and let it do it on its own terms.

Comment: In my start method i'm simply awaiting a list of tasks.
I'm assuming these are executed by the thread i started the start method from, right?

Comment: After doing some more debugging it turns out, that the thread has changed, after awaiting the first task.

Comment: You shouldn't mix tasks with async/await with threads, do one or the other, don't combine.

Comment: @MarcGravell was right then, your thread has terminated already. You should read up on how async/await and tasks and continuation tasks work.

Answer (score 3):

> In my start method i'm simply awaiting a list of tasks. I'm assuming these are executed by the thread i started the start method from, right?

Wrong.

When an `await` happens on an **incomplete** awaitable (typically: `Task` / `Task<T>` or `ValueTask<T>`), it registers a continuation and **returns**. If you return to the top of the call stack: your thread completes.

Separately, when the awaitable *completes*, the continuation will be invoked. This *could* be synchronously **on the thread that is doing the completion**, or it could be via a scheduler such as the sync-context.

The one thing it can't run on is the thread that did the `await`: because that thread has already finished.